# How to schedule local notification from iOS14 widget?

Tags: swift, widget, ios14

I would like to schedule a local notification from iOS14 widget.

How can I do it?

I tried implementing the following:

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Some Title"
    content.body = "Some Body"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString,
                content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error) in
       if error != nil {
          // Handle any errors.
       }
```

Comment: did you got any solution?

Comment: unfortunately, I did not

Comment: but I did yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I did with this.

```
    func createDate(day: Int, month : Int, hour: Int, minute: Int, year: Int)->Date{
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = hour
        components.minute = minute
        components.year = year
        components.day = day
        components.month = month
        components.timeZone = .current
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        return calendar.date(from: components)!
    }

  //  ///CreateNitification
    func scheduleNotification(at date: Date, identifierUnic : String, body: String, titles:String) {
        let triggerWeekly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .hour,.minute, .year], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = titles
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.categoryIdentifier = "todoList2"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifierUnic, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
      //  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        /// UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ["textNotification2"])
        /// UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(" We had an error: \(error)")
            }}
    }

// Call 
func callNotifications(){
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    let adte =  createDate(day: 3, month: 6, hour: 16, minute: 51, year: 2021)
    scheduleNotification(at: adte, identifierUnic: UUID().uuidString, body: "Widgets on Work", titles: "check 123")
}
 func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        callNotifications()
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

> Notification is working fine
> but one thing is pending, how can I call UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self?
> Thanks